# rewind() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm using code igniter 3 to create my project. In local server its working fine but when i upload in server i got error.
Please any one suggest what is the problem how can i resolve ?

Erro:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: rewind() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 188

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: filesize(): stat failed for /tmp/ci_session3ef560e62f7a107dafac77cf3bfb342c7c50c1de

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 192

Backtrace:

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  fopen(/tmp/ci_session3ef560e62f7a107dafac77cf3bfb342c7c50c1de): failed to open stream: No such file or directory</p>
<p>Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 156</p>
```

Comment: `fopen` will return resource handle on success, and boolean on failure. If `fopen` fails and you feed it into `rewind`, it will cause the error that you mentioned. You should check if the file exists and have appropriate permission.

Comment: Thanks frz3993  , Actualy  i solve my problem just removing  session varibale from autoload function in config  file, but still i don't no   why this problem occur.

Comment: Many framework use their own implementation of session handling, it's hard to be sure. But, it seems like the ci session file was not found or can't be opened.